# Google Tag Manager DataLayer not allways Pushing

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a Tag in tag manager that feeds me back the data of fields that have been showing as invalid when a user tries to submit a form but its missing or has invalid fields.

This is done using the following code:

```js
  // Get user Agent
  var Uagent = navigator.userAgent;
                        
  // Validation Errors Check
  document.getElementById("btnSubmit").onclick = function() {
  errorLoop();
}

function errorLoop() {
  var runner = document.getElementsByClassName("invalid"),
      formEmail = document.getElementById('email').value,
    dataL = [];
  dataLayer.push({'formEmail' : formEmail});

  if (runner) {

    for (var i = 0; i < runner.length; i++) {
      var errName = runner[i].getAttribute("name"),
        errId = runner[i]
        .getAttribute("id");

      dataL.push("Field: " + errName + " - ID: " + errId);
    } //End for

    dataL.toString();
    var vadout = dataL + " Device: " + Uagent;
    
    console.log(dataL);

    dataLayer.push({
      'formEmail' : formEmail,
      'validationError': vadout,
      'event' : 'errorpush'
    });


  } //End if
} //End errorLoop
```

So whats basically happening here is on a submit we are checking the form to see if any of the fields have the class `invalid` & if it does then it add's the name & Id of the fields to an array then prints then prints the array into a data layer.

The tag itself is triggered using a custom event called `errorpush`.

The issue is that this works only about 80% of the time we still get alot of people get validation errors but the validation errors don't seem to make it to the datalayer and back to google analytics.

I'm considering adding a settimeout delay to the datalayer push which I will go away and try but wanted to see if anyone knows of anything right off the bat which could be causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your runner is declared as empty array if there are no elements with class name "invalid". But your if statement is only checking for declaration thus:

```
if(runner){

}
```

will always be true but there are no "invalid" elements. Consequently `dataL.push("Field: " + errName + " - ID: " + errId);`will never execute in your for loop but `dataLayer.push` will, and so you will get errorpush event without any errors.

To solve this, I would suggest to rewrite your if statement:

```
if(runner.length > 0){

}
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I think you may have misread the code. Runner only runs if class invalid is on page. It does not run without an invalid class. so there is never any point where its a false positive like you suggest. adding length will not change anything. P.s. I really should have answered this question myself as I was right about my original assumption about the datalayer pushing to soon for the loop to finish adding timeout fixed the issue.

Comment: No I think you misread my answer, your if statement checks if runner exists. If you declare runner as empty array(when elements with class name "invalid" do not exist) it still exists as empty array varible and so your if statemnt will still run. Please check it in console and let me know if I am not right.

Comment: Already checked it doesn't effect anything. the issue is the datalayer goes to GA before the loop finished processing. already resolved like I said.

Comment: Please have a look at this code: https://jsfiddle.net/7dfjs69y/ 

I am happy you resolved your problem, but the code you provided in your question is synchronous, the ga code (dataLayer.push) will never execute before for loop is finished.